# Robot Framework Properties File

Tags: internationalization, robotframework

I am using robot framework for web automation and I am wondering how to set up a properties files such as config.properties in Java in order to set different assertions for example depending on the language used.

For example :

Let's say I would like to assert a title of a page.

```
Location Should be  Title in English
Location Should be  Title in French
Location Should be  Title in Italian
```

Is there a way to use only one assertion in my test case and use a different file that will do the corresponding assertion depending on the language of the website : website.com, website.fr, website.it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some research I have found out that robot framework offers the possibility of doing this through variables files.
Variable files are python module where I can simply set variables for each website version : EN,FR,IT
Example of varfilefr :

```
TITLE = "title in french"
```

In my tests case I would use

```
${TITLE}
```

Then in command line I enter the variable files as parameter, all variables set in variable file will be taken in account when running the test.

```
pybot  -vbrowser:firefox -vbaseurl:FRURL --variablefile frvariablefile.py test.robot
```